# Custom pin with title subtitle iphone

Tags: iphone, android-mapview

I have a mapview and i put an annotation which shows a custom title and subtitle pin.
When the mapview starts the pin is visible but the title and subtitle are not.
I have to press on the pin to show up the title and subtitle. Is it possible to show the title and subtitle without pressing the pin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/19740-trigger-mkannotationview-callout-bubble.html#post110447

anyway guys seems to be a problem at xcode specific version check the above link. this is working

Answer (score 0):

this is just a suggestion but you can try

> ```
> [myCustomAnnotationView becomeFirstResponder];
> ```

Comment: - (MKAnnotationView *) mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>) annotation{

 MKPinAnnotationView *newAnnotation = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"annotation1"];
 
 newAnnotation.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorGreen;
 newAnnotation.animatesDrop=TRUE;
 newAnnotation.canShowCallout=YES;
 
 [newAnnotation becomeFirstResponder];

 return newAnnotation;
}

I have put it here but its not working!

Answer (score 0):

you could use

```
  MKMapView *mapView;
  id<MKAnnotation> myAnnotation;
  // initialize mapView and myAnnotation...
  [mapView selectAnnotation:myAnnotation animated:YES]
```

Comment: yes, I have used this method in a number of applications, where are you calling this from?